# conformance vs. inheritance in Cocoa/Objective-C classes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, class, inheritance

I noticed that Cocoa/Objective-C classes inherit and conform from other classes. I understand what inheritance is, but not conformance. What's the difference?

Also, is a class like UIView a Cocoa class or an Objective-C class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes don't conform to classes, they conform to [protocols](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/articles/ocProtocols.html), which are basically lists of messages that a class can respond to. If a class conforms to a protocol, it must respond to all the non-optional messages listed in the protocol interface.

Also, there isn't really a difference between a Cocoa class and an Objective-C class. Cocoa is an Objective-C framework, so all of its classes are Objective-C classes. If you're asking whether classes like UIView are part of the language or the framework: Every class you normally interact with in a Cocoa/Cocoa Touch app comes from the framework. The native classes the standard Objective-C runtime provides are:

- Object
- Protocol
- List

You can go to /usr/include/objc if you want to see the headers for yourself. None of these are used in a normal Cocoa or Cocoa Touch program. You do use Protocols (as mentioned above), but don't normally refer to the class directly.

Comment: I've seen things conform to NSObject. Isn't that an object and not a protcol?

Comment: @awakeFromNib: It's both. There is an NSObject class and a protocol named NSObject to which the class conforms. Class: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html  Protocol: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSObject

Comment: what's "List"? can't find it in my runtime

Comment: @user102008: Like I said, look in /usr/include/objc/List.h. It's there on my Snow Leopard system, at least.

Comment: @Chuck: that is not available in objective-c 2.0

Comment: @user102008: That's true, it's deprecated nowadays. Did you actually want to use it? It hasn't been useful in a very long time, before OS X came out.

Answer (score 1):

Conformance or more accurately conforming to a protocol is simply Objective C's way of specifying behavior that the class should implement, similar to a java interface.

UIView is part of the UIKit framework so it is a Cocoa class.

Comment: No, UIView is part of the UIKit framework, so it is a *Cocoa Touch* class. UIKit is not part of Cocoa.

Answer (score 1):

Conformance is more or less the same as assignability. 
But i never saw this second term used used for it.

If you can assign an object to a variable b then a conforms to b.

Comment: Except that in Objective-C, you can assign a pointer to an instance of any class to any pointer variable, including a variable declared as holding a pointer to an instance of a completely unrelated class.